# Como adiciono um array dentro de uma matrix em python

Tags: python, array, lista, matriz

Olá estou com um problema no python eu estou tirando de um excel um matrix de 15 colunas e 3 linhas, então eu estou lendo o excel com o pandas e fiz esse while abaixo para ler todas as colunas e todas as linhas:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from collections import Counter
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from pandas import ExcelFile
from openpyxl import load_workbook

loto = pd.read_excel(r'lotofacil2.xlsx')

numlinesandcols = loto.shape

print(numlinesandcols)

cont = 0
matrix = []
matrix2 = []
line = []
contcolum = 1
contline = 0

while(contcolum != 16 and contline <= 2):
    colunm = 'Bola' + str(contcolum)
    valuenumber = loto.loc[contline, colunm]
    int(contcolum)
    print(contline, contcolum)
    line.append(valuenumber)
    contcolum = contcolum + 1
    print(colunm)
    print(valuenumber)
    if contcolum == 16 and contline <= 2:
        print(line)
        print('entrou no IF')
        matrix.append(line)
        # np.concatenate((matrix, line))
        print(matrix)
        line.clear()
        print(line)
        contcolum = contcolum - 15
        contline = contline + 1
        tamanhoMatrix = len(matrix)
        print(tamanhoMatrix)
else:
    print('fim do código')


print(matrix2)
```

Mas quando ele imprime a matrix ao invés de me retornar esse resultado:

> [[18, 20, 25, 23, 10, 11, 24, 14, 6, 2, 13, 9, 5, 16, 3], [23, 15, 5, 4, 12, 16, 20, 6, 11, 19, 24, 1, 9, 13, 7], [20, 23, 12, 8, 6, 1, 7, 11, 14, 4, 16, 10, 9, 17, 24]]

Ele está me retornando esse resultado:

> [[23, 12, 8, 6, 1, 7, 11, 14, 4, 16, 10, 9, 17, 24], [23, 12, 8, 6, 1, 7, 11, 14, 4, 16, 10, 9, 17, 24], [23, 12, 8, 6, 1, 7, 11, 14, 4, 16, 
>   10, 9, 17, 24]]

Ou seja, ele sobrescreve os arrays anteriores, tem alguma forma de concatenar o array novo com os anteriores na matrix?

Comment: Coloquei todo o código, eu sou nova no python então por isso não consegui uma solução mais simples, pode me ajudar? E sobre os dados não os 3 arrays do exemplo de resposta certa, eles devem estar dentro de um excel.

Comment: Joana e o arquivo `lotofacil2.xlsx` para poder testarmos o programa?

Comment: Como eu adiciono o arquivo a pergunta?

Comment: É muito grande? Você poderia colocar umas três linhas na pergunta e deixar um link para o arquivo completo.

Answer (score 0):

> Ou seja, ele sobrescreve os arrays anteriores, tem alguma forma de concatenar o array novo com os anteriores na matrix?

Isso acontece porque você criou os objetos listas foras do while. Portanto, a cada iteração do while, você esta utilizando a mesma lista (line), e a lista matix está recebendo múltiplas vezes a referencia da lista 'line'.